# Windows ECS Task Definition - Network Mode Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to set up a Windows container on Amazon ECS but running into problems when creating a "task definition".

When I try and create a task definition in ECS, the "network modes" I can choose are "bridge", "host" or "none". If I use "bridge" or "host", I get an error on my EC2 machine:

"CannotStartContainerError: API error (404): network bridge not found"

My understanding is that different networking modes need to be used for Windows.

I came across [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=761161) thread after which I tried to use the AWS CLI and removed "network mode" from the JSON file completely. This approach was also stated in the official AWS Docker documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/windows_task_definitions.html).

However I found that the "network mode" defaulted to "bridge" anyway and the same error resulted. If I remove "network" mode from the JSON configuration in the console, then I am unable to create the "task definition" - I need to select one of the options "bridge", "host" or "none".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This will help: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=761161

Edit with json, remove the property of networkMode.